# How to make jupyter pythreejs plots larger?

Tags: python, three.js, widget, jupyter-notebook

I've been playing around with pythreejs, and, while it seems to be a good solution to the problem of visualizing 3D graphics in a jupyter notebook, I haven't been able to find any documentation about what jupyter is actually doing under the hood or what API exists for managing the widget. Currently, when I make a pythreejs plot (e.g., by calling `display()` on a `pythreejs.Renderer` object), I get a tiny little output window. How can I edit the size (and other properties) of this window? How can I see what the properties are?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I discovered by experimentation that this can be controlled by passing the `width` and `height` parameters to the `pythreejs.Renderer` constructor. I would, however, appreciate any answer that points me toward better documentation for pythreejs or some philosophy regarding why/how certain aspects of the three.js API were modified for Python's API.